# how to jump to another jade file from a jade file using hyperlink

Tags: pug

//in index.jade

a(href="another.jade") //I try this way,but it don't work

I put two jade files into same directory,how to jump to anther jade file form index jade file using hyperlink,not use redirect!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Jade is a templating language. It converts to HTML before being delivered to client. Jade is inaccessible to client directly. Only the HTML that it converts to is accessible to the client. So you can't link to another Jade file.